# What to do when custom index is not an option in Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my Cloud Firestore database I have a collection of `users` and a collection of `events`. A `user` can attend to multiple events by requesting them to the owner, so in every `event` I keep track of this as shown below:

[image]
A query to get all the events a `user` is participating in is:

```
String participating = "participants_id." + myUserID;
query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("events").whereEqualTo(participating, true);
```

The problem is that if I want to paginate these results I need to `order` and `limit` the query and this requires a custom index. So this index would be required for each `"participants_id." + myUserID` field, which is not scalable (max custom index are 200).

So how can I solve this? I could denormalize the `events` collection and add a `participating` subcollection for each user copying the event document there as well. But I would prefer to avoid denormalizing if possible since it becomes a bit messy. Is there any better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cloud Firestore` automatically creates [indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) on individual fields of your documents. Complex indexes that span multiple fields can only be created manually in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/). Unfortunately, you cannot programmatically create indexes, at least for the moment.

In your scenario, you should definitely use denormalization. One reason for using denormalization is because there is also a limit regarding the maximum size for a document, which is `1Mib`. So if you have too many participants, you can reach this limit very quickly. See here [Firestore quotas and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).

So, you typically should consider augmenting your data structure to allow a reverse lookup. For example, I'd add a `participating` subcollection where you keep the lists for each user or you can add it as a top level collection and your database structure should look like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
   |      |
   |      --- userId (document)
   |           |
   |           --- //user details
   |
   --- userEvents (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- userId (document)
   |           |
   |           --- events (collection)
   |                 |
   |                 --- eventId
   |                       |
   |                       --- //event details
   |
   --- events (collection)
         |
         --- eventId (document)
               |
               --- //event details
```

Using this database structure, you can query your database very quickly to get all the events that correspond to a specific user. And as far as I know these are the only options that you have.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. In your database structure, how would you query all the events? A user needs to see all the events he/she is not participating in order to request them.

Comment: As in my updated answer. See, we have now a collection that contains all events and a collection `userEvents` that contains all the events that correspond to each user.
I have exaplained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** step by step, how you can **[structure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idywm80Qbvc&index=4&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&t=124s)** a similar database as yours.

Comment: Alright, I'll dig in your tutorial and  come back to this later. Thank you.

Comment: I've watched the tutorial and it is very cool, thanks for that. So I will definitely create the equivalent of a "joint table" and remove the field as `participants_id` and so on. Just a question - Is it better to create this collection as a subcollection of `users` or create the top collection `userEvents` ?

Comment: Yes, I will accept it. I was just getting the last bit of information before that ;)

Comment: Watching you tutorials I have realized though that I might need a `participants_id` field anyway for notification purposes. What do you think?

Comment: According to your use-case of your app, if you want to send notifications, then you should store the `participants_id`. Cheers!